# Find FileVault2 user in fdesetup output with Awk

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have 2 user profiles (fred, fredmoo) with filevault 2 enabled.

I have the following bash:

```
## Get the logged in user's name
userName=$(/usr/bin/stat -f%Su /dev/console)
```

This first user check sees if the logged in account is already authorized with FileVault 2

```
userCheck=`fdesetup list | awk -v usrN="$userName" -F, 'index($0, usrN) {print $1}'`
if [ "${userCheck}" != "${userName}" ]; then
    echo "This user is not a FileVault 2 enabled user."
    exit 3
fi
```

If I do `echo $userName`, I get

```
fred
```

If I do `echo $userCheck`, I get

```
fred fredmoo
```

The conditional statement above works well if there's only 1 profile. Unix or Linux Image, however since my mac has more than 1 user profile, the statement will echo "This user is not a FileVault 2 enabled user." and exit.

userCheck has both profiles.

How do I modify the if statement to say if userName does NOT equal to the 1st userCheck or 2nd userCheck, then echo "This user is not a FileVault 2 enabled user." and exit?

The output from [`fdesetup`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/fdesetup.8.html) `list` looks like this:

```
fredmoo,485A09Cf-B0D5-469A-8224-2DD1877E780B
administrator,DDB87E8D-8150-4D06-A59D-774AD28D119C
gollum,8AE6C365-E38F-49E2-998C-F4742CC9980C
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Awk script looks for `fred` anywhere in the `fdesetup` output, which of course it also finds when the output contains `fredmoo`.

You seem to have a comma-separated output that you are comparing against, so your Awk script should probably be something like `awk -v user="$(whoami)" -F , '$1 == user { print $1 }'` (where I assume output looks like in the sample here: https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2013/10/22/managing-mavericks-filevault-2-with-fdesetup/).

Also, a common antipattern is storing stuff you only need once in a variable, which just complicates things and pollutes your namespace.  Try to change your Awk script so that it sets the correct exit code; then you can use that directly in a conditional.  Maybe even refactor that into a reusable function.

```
warn () {
    echo "$0: $@" >&2
}
die () {
    rc=$1
    shift
    warn "$@"
    exit $rc
}

canihazfv2 () {
    fdesetup list |
    awk -v user="$1" -F , '$1 == user { print $1; exit 0 } END { exit 1 }'
}

me=$(whoami)
canihazfv2 "$me" || die 3 "$me is not enabled to use FileVault 2"
```

Notice also how the script identifies itself in the error message (so that when you build new scripts which call other scripts which call this script, you can see which one is actually failing three years from now) as well as the actual input which triggered the error, and prints the error message to standard error through redirection.

As always, `this || that` is shorthand for `if ! this; then that; fi` where of course the longhand might be preferable if `that` is something moderately complex (which I avoid here by also encapsulating `die` in a function).